# HTML Javascript multiple like buttons on a single page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a social media style website, that I want to have a like-feature for the posts, It's supposed to be very simple for now.

With this code, only the first post's like button works, so how do I make them individual, without having to rewrite code a thousand times?

Javascript:

```
const getLike = document.querySelector('.like');
const getLikeNum = document.querySelector('.likeNum');

let like = 0;

increaseLike = () => {
like ++
getLikeNum.innerHTML = `${like}`
}
    
likeClick = () => {
increaseLike()
}
    
getLike.addEventListener(('click'), likeClick)
```

HTML:

```
<div id="opslag-gruppe">
          <div class="opslag">
            <div class="bar">
              <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
              <p class="likeNum">0</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="opslag">
            <div class="bar">
              <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
              <p class="likeNum">0</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="opslag">
            <div class="bar">
              <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
              <p class="likeNum">0</p>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="opslag">
            <div class="bar">
              <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
              <p class="likeNum">0</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements with class `like`, and iterate over them.
2. When you iterate over each button have your `addEventListener` return a function (a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) that initialises the count, and maintains it only for that button. This way you don't need global variables.

```js
// Set the intial like to 0
function likeClick(like = 0) {

  // Return a new function that is called when
  // the click on the button is called
  return function (e) {

    // Find the closest `bar` parent
    const bar = e.target.closest('.bar');

    // Grab the `p` element within that parents child elements
    const likeNum = bar.querySelector('p');

    // Update the like variable
    likeNum.textContent = ++like;
  }
}

// Cache the elements
const getLike = document.querySelectorAll('.like');

// For every element add a listener that
// calls the function that initialises the count and
// returns the function that *is* called when the
// button is clicked, and updates the count
getLike.forEach(like => like.addEventListener('click', likeClick(), false));
```

```html
<div id="opslag-gruppe">
  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/704a70/fff&text=Click" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/704a70/fff&text=Click" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/704a70/fff&text=Click" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `querySelectorAll` to find ALL the buttons you can assign a simple event handler to each and simplify the whole process. That said the number of clicks really needs to be stored somewhere like a database otherwise it is ephemeral and lasts only as long as the pageview and is per-person. The problem with logging the number of clicks/likes in this example is that there is no unique identifiers assign to the individual items in the parent container ...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.like').forEach(bttn=>{
  bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    this.nextElementSibling.textContent=Number( this.nextElementSibling.textContent ) + 1;
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="opslag-gruppe">

  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="opslag">
    <div class="bar">
      <button class="like"><img src="hjerte.png" class="hjerte"></button>
      <p class="likeNum">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use querySelectorAll and then use forEach .

```js
const likeButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".likeButton")];

let likeCount = 0;


function like () {
  likeCount++;
  console.log(likeCount);
}

likeButtons.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", like);
});
```

```html
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
<button class="likeButton">Like</button>
```